# Unexpected character (at character 2) while parsing json using dio

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I was getting data from api using dio. It was successful but when data gets and it gets an exception.

Unexpected character (at character 2) {data:{id:5, name: ....

in error log, shows an arrow in beneath d(data)

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed responsetype only for this API. It worked.

```
await dio.get(
    url, 
    options: Options(
        responseType: ResponseType.plain,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Dio however, I had this error when accessing data from the local repository (Shared Preferences).

After hours I discovered that the data was not correctly saved as a json string which made the decoding throw an error.

Correct way.

```
await _prefs?.setStringList(
       _itemsKey, itemsJson.map((e) => json.encode(e)).toList());
```